# KVM switch, many console to one computer

Tags: kvm-switch, multiple-users

I understand KVM's purpose is to control multiple computers from one place (one set of KVM). I am looking for a device that functions the other way around! That is, control/work-on single computer from many places (multiple set of KVM).
Planning to run a computer training centre where each student can login to the server and work using his/her KVM. My objective here is cost cutting.

Is there such a device? Is what I am looking for makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

For monitors, just use a vga splitter to connect the server output to multiple monitors.

For keyboards and mice, try connecting them through usb hub to the server.

Comment: Could you please provide some link where the setup you've suggested is demonstrated/explained?!

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop is an option though it wouldn't be cheap if you didn't already have computers. We need more details. Will the server be near the students? Like in the same room or will you be traveling from school to school? It is possible to have multiple keyboards and mice attached to one computer.

Comment: You can assume a 15x30 sqft room where students (approx 20) are placed with adequate space between them and I'd like to provide a KVM set on each table. The server is placed in a corner of the room.